# How to prevent node caching

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I've created a dynamic force-directed network map using d3.js. The map initially fetches all network nodes and displays them correctly with network interfaces displayed as lines joining nodes together. This all works fine.

When a user decides to filter on network interfaces belonging to specific projects, that's where I run into problems. I reuse the same d3.layout.force instance and run the same function which initially creates map, but with new data. In order to keep things simple, I've compacted the source quite a lot, removing all things not relevant to the question.

```
var _this = {
    graphLayout     : d3.layout.force(),
    node : null,
    link : null,
    selectedProject : null,

    /*****************************************************
        Initialize engine
     *****************************************************/
    render : function() {
        // Creates the SVG container, sets up markers and gradients and whatnots
        // unnecessary for me to include here I think.

        // Start simulation
        _this.update();

        // Apply event handling and set up onTick
    },

    /*****************************************************
        Perform a data update. This will read data from an
        external url, and redraw all graphics.
     *****************************************************/
    update : function(project) {
        if (project !== undefined) {
            _this.selectedProject = project;
        }

        url = 'someService'+(!project ? '/GetNodes' : '/GetNodesByProjectId?projectId='+project.ProjectNumber);
        d3.json(url, function(json) {
            // Update nodes based on data
            // Apply data to graph layout
            _this.graphLayout
                .nodes(json.nodes)
                .links(json.links)
                // Even more parameters which are unnecessary for this question
                .start();

            // Join lines config
            _this.link = d3.select(" svg > .lineContainer").selectAll("g.link").data(_this.graphLayout.links());
            var group = _this.link.enter().append("svg:g")
                // More attributes and click event handling for the lines
                .attr('id',         function(d) { return d.InterfaceNumber; });
            group.append("svg:line");
            _this.link.exit().remove();

            // Node rendering config
            _this.node = d3.select(" svg > .nodeContainer").selectAll("g.node").data(_this.graphLayout.nodes());
            group = _this.node.enter().append("svg:g")
                // More attributes and click event handling for the nodes
                .attr('id',         function(d) { return d.Id; });
            group.append("svg:path")
                .attr("d", _this.nodeSVGPath)
                .attr("fill",       function(d) { return "url(#blackGradient)"; });
```

And here is where I run into my issue:

```
            // Add label to node
            group.append('svg:text').attr('class', 'label').attr('transform', 'translate(25, 30)').text(function(d,i) { return d.Name; });
            _this.node.exit().remove();
        });
    },
```

The function(d,i) placed on .text here does not seem to run when update is called the second time. Is something being cached in d3 here, or am I missing something?

The problem here is that the node (or line) contains the correct **data** object, but the text presented on the node does not match, which leads me to believe that d3js has reused the svg object completelly, but exchanged the **data** with the newly updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing this one important fact.  The enter() function creates a subselection of data for which there is not already an element.  Here's what you should do instead:

```
// Node rendering config
_this.node = d3.select(" svg > .nodeContainer").selectAll("g.node").data(_this.graphLayout.nodes());
group = _this.node.enter().append("svg:g")
// More attributes and click event handling for the nodes
    .attr('id', function(d) { return d.Id; });
group.append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", _this.nodeSVGPath)
    .attr("fill",       function(d) { return "url(#blackGradient)"; });
    // Add label to node
group.append('svg:text').attr('class', 'label').attr('transform', 'translate(25, 30)');

// now set the text for all g.node > g > text elements, new or old
_this.node.select('g > text').text(function(d,i) { return d.Name; });

_this.node.exit().remove();
```

Because group is an enter() subselection of _this.node it will never contain elements created before each invocation.  At the end, where you set the text, select ALL text nodes, new or old by using _this.node instead of group.  Does that help?

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. The whole enter/update concept is a bit confusing and in my opinion poorly documented.